# Is it possible to run WSO2 Api Manager in Openshift?

Tags: api, wso2, openshift, wso2-api-manager

Could I have a WSO2 Api Manager in OpenShift?. I would like to know if someone has any experience about that. I've heard about others API Management Solutions with difficulties to be deployed in a Gear container. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's a experiment going on how to successfully deploy any WSO2 products on openshift with WSO2 clustering. This blog post will guide how WSO2 products can deploy on openshift v3.x **without** WSO2 clustering [Deploy WSO2 products on OpenShift v3](https://noelyahann.blogspot.com/2016/03/deploy-wso2-products-on-openshift-v3.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShift) and the [Technologies](https://www.openshift.com/features/technologies.html) supported through Openshift, You should be able to run WSO2 API Manager on it.

> OpenShift also supports binary programs that are web applications, so
>   long as they can run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. This allows the use
>   of arbitrary languages and frameworks.